# HighchartsJS show tooltip as chart animation is in progress

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to build a custom areaspline chart. This series has an animation of 15000. How can I display and hide each Y value as the chart loads/animates? Just like a tooltip that animates above the last loaded point of the graph.

Some of the code is as follows:

```
tooltip: {
enabled:true,
shared:true,
formatter: function() {
    var number;

    $.each(this.points, function(i, smth) {
        number = "Value: " + smth.y;
    });
    return number;
}
},
plotOptions: {
areaspline: {
    lineWidth: 1,
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    shadow: false,
    states: {
        hover: {
            lineWidth: 1
        }
    },
    treshold: null
}
},
series: [
{
    animation: {
        duration: 15000
    },
    fillColor: '#fff',
    color: '#fff',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    pointStart: 0,
    data: [51, 35, 41, 56, 22, 20, 34, 21, 58, 22, 20, 32, 41, 55, 22]
}
]
```

Comment: This animation should be runned during chart initialization or in other events ?

Comment: I already have the set of data present. So I know how many values I have from the start. As the chart area loads from left to right (how the animation makes it move) each value, point should be shown and hidden to the top in a tooltip. Just like a floater moves along and changes its value from left to right, as the chart animation is in progress.